# Electron doesn't load files properly

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

My Angular app is running perfectly in a web server,
e.g. by calling `ng serve` or after running `ng build` and deploying to a web server.

When I use electron-builder the app is built and can be installed without problems. But on startup it is blank and the DOM doesn't contain the index.html. (but in DevTools I can see it in sources in app.asar [DevTools after start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pUyP.png).

After one reload, the index.html, the *.js, *.css and all files in assets/* are reloaded and displayed in Electron and it works without any issue. (And are also shown in devTools) [DevTools after first reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwGWu.png)

If I now try to reload the app, it won't work anymore, Electron tries to open the current route, eg. /path/to/app.asar/home which doesn't exist instead of loading the index.html in app.asar and then open the route. [DevTools after reloading again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWBh6.png)

This is my main.js file:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const isWindows = process.platform === 'win32';
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow;
let childProcess

async function createMainWindow() {
    openExternalApp();
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            webviewTag: true
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadUrl(`file://${path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')}`);
    //mainWindow.removeMenu();
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
        mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
            console.log('Main window ready to show');
            mainWindow.show();
        })
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    createMainWindow;
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        if (childProcess) {
            killChildProcess(childProcess);
          }
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createMainWindow()
    }
});

function openExternalApp() {
    const appPath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), '..','..');

    var api
    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
        api = `${appPath}\\resources\\subprocess.exe`
    }
    else if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
        throw new Error('Not Implemented')
    }
    else {
        api = `${appPath}/resources/subprocess`;
    }
    childProcess = exec(api, { stdio: 'ignore' });
}

function killChildProcess(child) {
    if (isWindows) {
      // For Windows: Terminate the process tree using taskkill
      exec(`taskkill /pid ${child.pid} /T /F`);
    } else {
      // For Linux and POSIX systems: Use the negative PID to kill the process group
      process.kill(-child.pid);
    }
  }
```

And for the Electron build:

```json
"build": {
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist/electron"
    },
    "files": [
      {
        "from": "electron",
        "to": "./"
      },
      {
        "from": "dist/",
        "to": "./"
      }
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "resourcces/subprocess",
        "to": "subprocess"
      },
      {
        "from": "resourcces/subprocess.exe",
        "to": "subprocess.exe"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The Routing is configured here:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

// Importiere die Komponenten, die du routen möchtest
import {COMPONENTS} from **;

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'ROUTE', component: COMPONENT},
  { path: 'ROUTE/SUB', component: COMPONENT},
  { path: 'ROUTE2', component: COMPONENT},
  { path: 'ROUTE3', component: COMPONENT},
  { path: 'ROUTE3/SUB', component: COMPONENT},
  { path: 'ROUTE4', component: COMPONENT},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is imported in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
AppRoutingModule]})
```

Any idea how to fix this problem in Electron?

#### EDIT:

When I add this line of code to the main.js file, it loads fine on startup, but after a reload it still doesn't work:

`mainWindow.webContents.session.clearStorageData();`

Comment: not sure why it's not loading at first (loading from assets instead of dist?), but that 2nd reload/refresh not working sounds like the server is usually redirecting those requests.  (it's common to do that so that refresh/bookmarks work)  You may want to switch to Hash Location Strategy: https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy

Comment: Changing to hash location strategy didn't help. I still have the same problem, after a reload.  


`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`